# HTML: How do I vertical-align my text into center?

Tags: html, css

I tried with many different css property including vertical-align: center, I even tried 100% height and 100% width, but no luck. It's been almost a hour.

Text align only on middle horizontal and top on vertical but I want my text in center(middle on vertical). Any suggestion?

Here is my HTML code:

```css
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body
{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.welcome-section
{
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="welcome-section" class="welcome-section">
  <h1>Poseidon</h1>
  <p>Information Technology, Software Developer learner, and CTF Player.</p>
  <p>Security is a top priority!</p>
</section>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

Answer (score 1):

```css
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body
{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.welcome-section
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="welcome-section" class="welcome-section">
  <h1>Poseidon</h1>
  <p>Information Technology, Software Developer learner, and CTF Player.</p>
  <p>Security is a top priority!</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

for your problem you just need to set the size of the container.

```
.welcome-section
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

That should work

Answer (score 0):

```css
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body
{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.welcome-section
{
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top:40vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="welcome-section" class="welcome-section">
  <h1>Poseidon</h1>
  <p>Information Technology, Software Developer learner, and CTF Player.</p>
  <p>Security is a top priority!</p>
</section>
```

Comment: for full window height use vh not percentage and if want to move contents up and down change the value of top padding, and for keeping the section size controlled use box-sizing.

Comment: Your explanation should be part of your answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using flexbox like this.

```css
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body
{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.welcome-section
{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="welcome-section" class="welcome-section">
  <h1>Poseidon</h1>
  <p>Information Technology, Software Developer learner, and CTF Player.</p>
  <p>Security is a top priority!</p>
</section>
```